# ERROR in R: Assigned data must be compatible with existing data

Tags: r, error-handling, datatable, data-science

I have a table in data.table format in R:

```
dt <- data.table(currency = c("EUR","EUR","EUR","USD","USD","USD", "RON","RON","RON","RON","RON","EUR","EUR","USD","USD","USD", "RON","RON","RON","RON","RON"), date = c("2019-02-25","2019-02-25","2019-02-25","2019-02-25","2019-02-25","2019-02-25", "2019-02-25","2019-02-25","2019-02-25","2019-02-25","2019-02-25","2019-03-01","2019-03-01","2019-03-01","2019-03-01","2019-03-01", "2019-03-01","2019-03-01","2019-03-01","2019-03-01","2019-03-01"), y = c("0,1","0,2","0,2","0,1","0,1","0,15","0,1","0,2","0,3","0,1","0,1","0,15","0,1","0,1","0,25","0,3","0,1","0,1","0,15","0,1","0,2")
dt
```

I needed to use the following code:

```
dt <- dt|>
  group_by(currency, date)  |>
  mutate(N = row_number())  |>
  ungroup()  |>
  complete(currency, date, N) |>
  arrange(date, currency, N)
dt
```

Then I needed to do approximation: to create a new column "x" in the table which will include approximation of column "y" and fulfill missing values. For doing this I used code:

```
#a table with selected columns
m <- dt[,c("currency","date","N","y")]

#add column x to the table
m$x <- na.approx(m$y)
```

And then I get an error:

```
Error: Assigned data `na.approx(zero_rates_hist$zero_rate)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 1654800 rows.
x Assigned data has 1654653 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
```

Help me, please! Thank you.

Comment: Where is your `N`?

Comment: N is a row_number, it is calculated in the first code. Sorry, I edited, I wrote the wrong name of a variable.

Comment: Example doesn't work : "need at least two non-NA values to interpolate"

Answer (score 0):

I decided to replace code with approximation with the following one and now everything works!

```
#add column x to the table
m <- m %>%
  mutate(x = na.approx(y, na.rm="FALSE"))
```